# Exibir os valores que são iguais comparando as 2 matrizes

Tags: c

Pela primeira vez me vi perdido nos exercicios acho que não peguei bem a lógica, mas estou estudando para entender. Vou mostrar meu código fonte por completo é pequeno e a questão. Ai gostaria da ajuda de voces para entender aonde estou errando.

-----Leia duas matrizes 20 x 20 e escreva os valores da primeira que ocorrem em
qualquer posição da segunda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int matrizx[3][3], matrizy[3][3], i, j, cont = 0;
    printf("----Primeira Matriz----\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Informe os X valores da %dº linha \n", (cont = cont + 1));
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrizx[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("----Segunda Matriz----\n");
    cont = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Informe os Y valores da %dº linha \n", (cont = cont + 1));
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrizy[i][j]);

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (matrizx[i][j] == matrizy[i][j]) {
                    printf("%d", matrizx[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Pessoal nesse ultimo bloco que é resṕonsável por fazer a analise que é a questão, ele só consegue pegar os primeiros valores repetido, que ele encontrar entre as matrizes porem somente a primeira  linha que  ele encontrar que os valores são iguais e exibido tais valores mas ele não prossegui com a analise para exibir outros valores.
Tentei utilizar uma variavel auxiliar para ajudar a armazenar mas sem sucesso.
Aguardo respotas galera!

Comment: Você está verificando se os elementos **na mesma posição** das matrizes são iguais e não é isso o que o exercício pede. Uma solução é para cada elemento da primeira matriz comparar com **todos** os elementos da segunda matriz. Não tem muito sentido esta variável `cont`, basta imprimir `i+1`.

Answer (score -1):

Segue resolução sugerida utilizando python:

```
def verifica(matriz, numero):
   for linha in matriz:
      for coluna in linha:
         if coluna == numero:
            print(coluna)

for x in matriz1:
   for y in x:
      verifica(matriz2, y)
```

Observe que eu fiz no segundo bloco um loop pegando número por número da primeira matriz e aplicando na função criada no primeiro bloco. Essa função, por sua vez, percorre a segunda matriz comparando cada número desta com o número recebido no parâmetro da função.
Do jeito que vc havia feito, vc apenas comparava números em posições iguais, e a questão pede que basta ocorrer em qualquer posição da segunda. Por isso vc varre as duas matrizes, comparando a primeira com tudo que está na segunda.

Answer (score -1):

Dessa forma ai, você só está percorrendo os elementos das mesmas posições. Tente fazer algo nesse esboço aqui:

```
int v1 = 0, c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
do{
    if(matrizx[c1][c2] == matrizy[c1][c2]){
        printf("%d ", matrizx[c1][c2]);
    }
    c2++;
    if(c2 == 3){
        c2 = 0;
        c1++;
    }
}while(c1 != 3);
```

Evite trabalhar definindo valores estáticos. Pra teste ok, mas depois coloquei algo mais dinâmico, pode ser até pegando o valor do próprio usuário.